# Java : Extract numbers from a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I was trying to extract my data from a string by using regular expression.

My data looks like:

```
 12 170 0.11918
170  12 0.11918
 12 182 0.06361
182  12 0.06361
 12 198 0.05807
198  12 0.05807
 12 242 0.08457
242  12 0.08457
 11  30 0.08689
 30  11 0.08689
```

The problems here are the different number of whitespace between two numbers.

All in all i want to extract from each line  two Integers and one Double.
Therefore i tried to use regular expressions.

```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(([0-9]+.[0-9]*)|([0-9]*.[0-9]+)|([0-9]+))");
  Matcher m = p.matcher("  6    7781     0.01684000");
  while (m.find()) {
     System.out.println(m.group(0));  
  }
```

I now my regular expression doesn't work. Has anyone some help for a suitable regular expression therefore i can work with the data or any other help for me?

Comment: play a little bit with http://txt2re.com/

Comment: thanks for that help. Such an nice tool!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check http://txt2re.com/index-java.php3?s=%2012%20170%200.11918&11&5&12&4&13&1

you're probably interested in the int1, int2 and float1 below

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String txt=" 12 170 0.11918";

    String re1="(\\s+)";    // White Space 1
    String re2="(\\d+)";    // Integer Number 1
    String re3="(\\s+)";    // White Space 2
    String re4="(\\d+)";    // Integer Number 2
    String re5="(\\s+)";    // White Space 3
    String re6="([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])";  // Float 1

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    if (m.find())
    {
        String ws1=m.group(1);
        String int1=m.group(2);
        String ws2=m.group(3);
        String int2=m.group(4);
        String ws3=m.group(5);
        String float1=m.group(6);
        System.out.print("("+ws1.toString()+")"+"("+int1.toString()+")"+"("+ws2.toString()+")"+"("+int2.toString()+")"+"("+ws3.toString()+")"+"("+float1.toString()+")"+"\n");
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's not clear why you would want to specify CASE_INSENSITIVE on a pattern that is matching only numbers, sign symbols, decimal points, and spaces, or why you would want to specify DOTALL on a pattern that is matching a single line, although it does no harm.

Comment: just because the tool I am using (txt2re) uses this by default

Answer (score 2):

why not read each line and do a `line.trim().split("\\s+")`? If your project has already used guava, the `Splitter` could be used too.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a `Scanner`.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
scanner.useDelimiter(" ");
int int1 = scanner.nextInt()
int int2 = scanner.nextInt()
double double1 = scanner.nextDouble()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`([\d.]+)` - This will get all strings containing only digits or periods (.).

Edit:

I see you're wanting three groups out of a line. This instead, will help by ignoring white space, and grabbing the three groups of numbers. The leading `^` and trailing `$` ensure that you're only matching on a single line.

`^\s*?([\d.]+)\s*([\d.]+)\s*?([\d.]+)\s*?$`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (fix up the float part as needed) -

```
 # raw:  (?m)^\h*(\d+)\h+(\d+)\h+(\d*\.\d+)
 # quoted: "(?m)^\\h*(\\d+)\\h+(\\d+)\\h+(\\d*\\.\\d+)"

 (?m)             # Multi-line modifier
 ^                # BOL
 \h*              # optional, horizontal whitespace
 ( \d+ )          # (1), int
 \h+              # required, horizontal whitespace
 ( \d+ )          # (2), int
 \h+              # required, horizontal whitespace
 ( \d* \. \d+ )   # (3), float
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = " 12 170 0.11918\n" + "170  12 0.11918 \n"
            + " 12 182 0.06361\n" + "182  12 0.06361 \n"
            + " 12 198 0.05807\n" + "198  12 0.05807 \n"
            + " 12 242 0.08457\n" + "242  12 0.08457 \n"
            + " 11  30 0.08689\n" + " 30  11 0.08689 \n";

    String[] lines = s.split("\\n");

    for( String line : lines ) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
        scan.useDelimiter("\\s+");
        scan.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(scan.nextInt());
        System.out.println(scan.nextInt());
        System.out.println(scan.nextDouble());
    }
```

I would use a Scanner for this problem.